# How to use ES6 import with hyphen

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I really don't know how to do this and not sure how to google either.

Right now I have this

```
let source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
```

I would like to change to be import but this doesn't work

```
import {'vinyl-source-stream' as source} from 'vinyl-source-stream';
```

Comment: What does `'vinyl-source-stream'` look like? i.e. would it work without hyphens so hyphens are really the issue here?

Comment: It's npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that module even supports the ES6 import/export system, then what you want is  this:

```
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
```

Your version is attempting to import an exported value *named* `vinyl-source-stream` from the module; instead, you just want the module itself to be imported (into an object named `source` in this case).

If you want everything in the module imported, instead of just the default exports, use this instead:

```
import * as source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
```

But neither of those will work if the module isn't actually written to use the new system.

Answer (score 0):

This library doesn't use the ES2015 module system. It doesn't [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) at all, so you can't [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it or from it.

This library uses the CommonJS module pattern (as can be seen [in the source](https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-source-stream/blob/master/index.js)) and is meant to be `require`ed.

You could `import` the library with:

```
import form 'vinyl-source-stream';
```

which will cause the code to be executed, but that will be useless in this case since nothing (useful) will happen - in fact, you'll probably get a runtime exception due to undefined `module`.