# Identifier 'eye' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am developing app using ionic+react. In login page password field when using eye and eye-off icon, it's giving already been declared error. It seems issue with dash "eye-off". same issue if any other icon which has dash included.

```
./src/pages/Login.tsx
SyntaxError: D:\project\src\pages\Login.tsx: Identifier 'eye' has already been declared (12:28)

  10 | import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
  11 | import { IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol } from "@ionic/react";
> 12 | import { personCircle, eye, eye-off } from "ionicons/icons";
     |                             ^
  13 | import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
  14 | import {
  15 |   IonItem,
```

code page

```
<IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating"> Password</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
                  value={password}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                ></IonInput>
                <IonIcon icon={passwordShown ? eye : eye-off} onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity} slot="end"></IonIcon>
              </IonItem>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
```

Please suggest

Comment: You can't import something with a `-` in the name, that's not a valid variable. Are you sure that's not `eye_off` or `eyeOff`? You could also `import icons from '...'` and then `icons['eye-off']` if it's literally, and obnoxiously like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ES6 import with hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552545/how-to-use-es6-import-with-hyphen)

Comment: Here mention eye-off icon. how to use it? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/ionicons/